# How to catch JBoss exception in Java Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, exception, aop

I have a question related to aspect oriented programming in correlation with Java Web Services.

I have an application which is basically an inventory for a company's clients addresses. The data model has defined some pointcuts, so our custom rules get triggered in specific points (such as create, update, delete when we call the specific API which manipulates the address entities).

Now, i am creating an address entity through a java web service and persist it in the database. To create it, i call the specific cretion method provided by the application API. In this moment, the custom rules for creation are automatically fired and do some validation. Everything is fine until one of this custom rules crashes, throwing a custom exception. The problem i have is that i am not able to catch that exception in the web service. I mean, it gets thrown and everything, i can see it in the logs, but my handler doesn't see it and continues with the creation of my entity.

The error is caught only if i explicitly call the validation rule in my web service, but i don't want to do that, since i have a lot of rules for a particular entity and i would like to know if there's some sort of special error handling for this kind of problems.

PS: I am using JBoss rule engine.

Thanks!